# Why is my node.js not working properly with https?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

I have an apache server which works well with my letsencrypt setup. I can visit https:// and it works great. However, on a different port where i am running node.js, when i try visit it like with https, the connection is refused. then when i try with just http it works. So I did some research and I found out about `require('https')` module.

This is my updated server.js

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var routes = require('./routes');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var options = {
   key  : fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
   cert : fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);

https.createServer(options, app).listen(6767);
```

And to get the key.pem and cert.pem files i used:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
rm csr.pem
```

which successfully generate the two files in the home dir. I am not sure if they are configured correctly though.

So, now, I visited https://www.example.com:6767 and it works however in all browsers I get a "certificate warning" saying "this site may be trying to trick you, continue anyway?" etc etc and in chrome, it doesn't even allow you to "continue anyway". It blocks the server and shows:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from example.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
  Automatically report details of possible security incidents to Google. Privacy policy
```

How can i get rid of this weird perception the web seems to have about my server?

Thank you.

Comment: You buy a valid certificate, then your browser won't complain anymore

Comment: :( surely chrome cannot block me though?

Comment: It doesn't really block you, you can still enter on your own risk. However, to get rid of the warning you need an actual valid SSL certificate, and usually you have to pay for that, but there are free ones available as well.

Comment: I have lets encrypt....can i integrate that with node? will that sort this?